# Failed attempt at retrieving info from DB(Angular8, php)

Tags: php, angular, typescript

**UPDATE!** I can see retrieved data in preview but on **HTML** page there is nothing

[image]

**UPDATE2!** for Acuao[image]

I want to display Categories of OS from my DB [image]  but I'm getting this errors. I know this is a lot of code but I'm stuck. My DB is on OpenServer and I wrote in .htaccess. Also I'm relying on my prof's code but still nothing works

```
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-origin, referrer-policy, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin,
Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

category.ts

```
export class Category{
  num_os: number;
  name_os: string;
  constructor(num_os: number, name_os: string) {
    this.num_os = num_os;
    this.name_os = name_os;
  }
}
```

tovar.service.ts

```
import {Category} from './category';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from './http.service';

@Injectable()
export class TovarService{
 category: Category[];
 constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
   this.category = [];
 }
 getCategory = (): Category[] => {
   this.httpService.getCategory()
     .subscribe((resp: Response) => {
       for (let index in resp){
         let cat1: Category = new Category(resp[index].num_os, resp[index].name_os);
         this.category.push(cat1);
       }
     });
   return this.category;
 }
}
```

browse.component.html

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; color: whitesmoke;">
          <li>OS</li>
       <li *ngFor="let item of Categories; let i = index ">
            <a>{{item.name_os}}</a>
          </li>
</ul>
```

category.php

```
<?
include('connection.php');
$result3=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * from OS") or die("can't retrieve");
if(&result3){
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
  $obj1 = array();
  for($i =0; $i <$rows; ++$i){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);
    $obj1[$i]["NUM_OS"] = $row[0];
    $obj1[$i]["NAME_OS"] = $row[1];
      }
  echo json_encode($obj1);
  mysqli_free_result($result3);
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

browse.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Category} from '../shared/category';
import {TovarService} from '../shared/tovar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-browse',
  templateUrl: './browse.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./browse.component.css']
})
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {
NewCategory: Category[];
  constructor(private tovarservice: TovarService) {
    this.NewCategory = [];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.NewCategory = this.tovarservice.getCategory();
  }

}
```

http.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Category} from './category';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getCategory(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/category.php').pipe(
      map(resp => resp),
      catchError((error: any) => throwError(error)));
  }
}
```

Comment: i did as following but cors error remains

Comment: my proxy config is the same as in the link you provided

Comment: `{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "secure": false
  }
}
`
like this?

Comment: @bubbles it still doesnt work i'm afraid

Comment: @bubbles https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8wgpei?file=src/app/app.module.ts
first time using it

Comment: @bubbles i moved all the header Access to my category.php file, errors in console are no longer there but still info from Db is not shown

Comment: @bubbles yeah of course! one moment tho when i click inspect code in browser, network shows me that i indeed retrieve info from DB but it's just not showing on my page and this is the problem

Comment: to be more focus you need another question ... how did you fix your original bug ?

Comment: @bubbles i added my headers to a php file where there is a query(getting Category table)  to DB. Maybe I will post another question regarding the new problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure that when your are calling directly (curl or in the browser) `http://localhost/category.php` it returns the desired result (in json).

After that create a new file **proxy.conf.json** in the root of the src folder :

```json
{
    "/category.php": {
        "target": "http://localhost/category.php",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

Now we need to configure **angular.json** with **proxyConfig** key under the **architect>serve>options** that point to the **src/proxy.conf.json** as below :

```json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "demo:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "demo:build:production",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json" //this is the line to add
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, run your app as usual : **ng serve**

***NB: CORS backend headers are no longer needed***

Comment: For me disabling cors is not the solution.
@Ifwehadamonkey did you tryed to debug your php's response headers ?

Comment: disabling it ? I didn't !!

Comment: By using proxy you're bypassing CORS right ?

Comment: @Acuao i added headers to my category.php and now I can see info I'm trying to get in browser console but the new problem is that the info from DB is not showing on my browser page(html) and I dont know whats wrong

Comment: Can you send us a picture of the response headers inside your debugger ?
Is theres any redirect ? i recently had some similar issues caused by https redirect made by symfony.

Comment: @Acuao i'm sorry I don't know how to get response headers inside my debugger... not a native speaker, please tell me step by step how to do it

Comment: Follow the instructions of my last answer. (about using firefox for better network-debugging tools)
i'm not a native english speaker too, no worries  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers blocks AJAX request which are not on the same host.

Your problem does not come from your type script, you should take a look to CORS.
Your php should return a specific header in order to allow the Ajax call.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

for better understanding you can take a look at the following link :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

in a first step you can use the * value for testing, but after you should use your  app host/domain

Answer (score 0):

CORS system uses a preflight request using OPTIONS method to check the various CORS headers.

I notice that you're using chrome. CORS's debug is more difficult on chrome, since preflight requests(OPTIONS) are hidden on this browser.

I suggest you to use firefox to debug your problem. (firefox, which shows OPTIONS requests)

You should find a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header inside the OPTIONS response, not in the GET/POST requests.

If it is not the case you should solve this point.

Comment: please look at my screenshot i added, i'm not sure if i'm looking at the right thing but there is no OPTIONS response

Comment: Using Firefox, open the network pane BEFORE the very first call of your request.
You should then be able to see the OPTIONS request which is sent. as on the following screenshot.
i've been making many tests to reproduce your problem..
https://i.imgur.com/mfH4sXy.png

check the headers on the OPTIONS request, we don't care about the headers which are on the GET/POST requests

Comment: Also, the preflights request(OPTIONS) is not made every time (it's cached to improve performances), i just noticed that checking the checkbox disable seems to make a preflight request before each call. This is probably why you did not see the OPTIONS request before.

Comment: Did it helped you?

Comment: please vote to close the question. I found the solution

Comment: Ok, great! What was the exact problem and the solution? If we helped you consider voting on answers or and accept an answer.

Comment: i made all the variables that correspond to fields in DB in uppercase because in DB fields are in uppercase. i didn't change anything else besides that and now it works. Thank you for trying to help. I truly appreciate your patience with me.